# How to fixed left part and scroll right part and once reached the end then set position relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu, body content, and footer. My header menu is fixed.

Let's talk about body content.

In the body, I have two part which is left and right. Left is fixed and right part will scroll to the last content. Once reached the last the left and right both will set position relative.

I am trying to set left part fixed and scroll right part scroll once reached the end of the scroll then set position relative so that left and right will scroll at the end.

Would you help me out in this?

[image]

```css
html,body{margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 100%;}
header{background-color: #f8f8f8;position: fixed;width: 100%;z-index: 999;top: 0;}
ul{list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
ul li{display: inline-block;margin: 20px;}
ul li a{font-size: 18px;color: #000;}
.body_content{margin-top: 80px;position: relative; width: 100%; display: flex;}
#left {width: 30%;border: 1px solid #000;}
#left img{width: 100%;}
#right {width: 70%;}
#right p{padding: 10px 40px;}
footer{position: relative;background-color: #ccc;}
```

```html
<header>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SERVICE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<div class="body_content">
    <div id="left">
<img src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Child-Girl-with-Sunflowers-Images.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="right">

        <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


                <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    </div>
    </div> 

<div style="background-color: #f3f3f3;padding: 20px 0;font-size: 18px;">
                <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
    <footer>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SERVICE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
```

Comment: do you mean the image is supposed to be `fixed` until it reaches the end of the container with the black border?

Comment: Yes, Image will be fixed till the end and once reached the end then image position will set relative

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```css
        html,body{margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 100%;}
        header{background-color: #f8f8f8;position: fixed;width: 100%;z-index: 999;top: 0;}
        ul{list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
        ul li{display: inline-block;margin: 20px;}
        ul li a{font-size: 18px;color: #000;}
        .body_content{margin-top: 80px;position: relative; width: 100%; display: flex;}
        #left {width: 30%;border: 1px solid #000;
         /*ADD BELOW TWO LINES*/
           position: fixed;
          top: 61px;
    }
        #left img{width: 100%;}
        #right {width: 70%;
        /** ADD BELOW LINES **/ 
        position: relative;
      right: 0;
      left: 570px;
        }
        #right p{padding: 10px 40px;}
        footer{position: relative;background-color: #ccc;}
```

```html
        <header>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SERVICE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<div class="body_content">
    <div id="left">
<img src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Child-Girl-with-Sunflowers-Images.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="right">

        <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


                <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    </div>
    </div> 

<div style="background-color: #f3f3f3;padding: 20px 0;font-size: 18px;">
                <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
    <footer>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SERVICE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
```

But this is not a responsive and reliable solution
You Can use this jQuery plugin for handling fixed Sidebars or sidebar contents; You can get it from here
https://github.com/ismailfarooq/simple-sticky-sidebar

There are many other plugins, that you can use, but i like this one most and it is very simple to use.

In your case you can just use it like this

`simpleStickySidebar('#left', {
    container: '.sidebar', // sidebar relative element
    topSpace: 61 // Default : 0
    bottomSpace: 20 // Default : 0
});`

Comment: At the end, I have to set position relative to the image so that image can scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: sticky` for this. It's basically a mixture of `position: fixed` and `position: relative` changing after certain thresholds depending on how far you have scrolled. You will need to define either `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` for it to work.

In this case I used `top: 60px;` (instead of for instance `top: 0px;`), because otherwise the navigation would be over the image. Keep in mind that the support is [slightly limited](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) in some browsers.

**Here's a demonstration with the snippet you provided before:**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
}

.body_content {
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#left img {
  width: 100%;
}

#right {
  width: 70%;
}

#right p {
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#left img {
  position: sticky;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="">SERVICE</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="body_content">
  <div id="left">
    <img src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Child-Girl-with-Sunflowers-Images.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="right">

    <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
      ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
      ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


    <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
      ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
      ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  </div>
</div>

<div style="background-color: #f3f3f3;padding: 20px 0;font-size: 18px;">
  <p>Lots of scrollable content goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
    in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="">SERVICE</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```